# Leading Zero Before Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a leading zero before time in (12 Hrs Format)

Example:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0), 100), 7)
```

The result is 1:00PM

I am expected result like **01:00PM**

But, when I try below code it works

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000'+'1:00PM',7)
```

I want to know why the first query not given the expected result.

Comment: Why not   select format( getdate(), 'hh:mmtt')

Comment: I suggest you format data in the app presentation layer instead of T-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'hh:mmtt') as time
```

The result is: **07:30AM**

```
SELECT FORMAT (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0), 'hh:mmtt') as time
```

The result is : **01:00PM**

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
 select '"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0), 100) + '"'
```

You will get:

```
"Jan  1 1900  1:00PM"
```

I'm not sure why you think that prepending `'0000000'` and taking the last seven characters would do what you want.

It is a little hard to figure out what you really want, because you are starting with a constant that has the format you want.

If you want a zero-padded 12-hour time format, you can use:

```
select right('0' + convert(varchar(255), convert(time, getdate()), 100), 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0), 100)
```

will give you this result: **Jan  1 1900  1:00PM**

This part:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0)
```

will return this: **1900-01-01 13:00:00.000**

What is the goal here ?
I agree with the option provided from @SANDEEP answer.

[Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efc876acc0eda7d608905f99f9d81e47)

Answer (score 0):

Just try it step by step to see what is happening:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0)
--> 1900-01-01T13:00:00Z

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0))
--> Jan 1 1900 1:00PM

SELECT '0000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0))
--> 0000000Jan 1 1900 1:00PM
```

And the seven rightmost letters of the last expression are, obviously, `1:00PM`.

As others have suggested, use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (SQL Server 2012 and above) instead:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '01:00PM', 0), 'hh:mmtt')
--> 01:00PM
```